# AWS-SDK/client-s3 Extracting and reading gzip files

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I have a large number of `.gz`s
files - these files are not very big but there are about 100 of them - on a AWS S3 bucket. I need to pull them, unzip the file, read the content of the files and apply some filter, save those that pass the filter into memory and finally delete the file(s) on S3.

Env:

- `@aws-sdk/client-s3 v3.513.0` SDK
- `Node v16.4.2`

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That seems like a fine starting point.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Not sure how to do it... at a higher level it seems pretty straight forward but somehow no matter what I do I'm unable to download the files within a directory to a local directory.